# Add data to array PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an existing array named `$list` I want to add new field or data in that array but I dont know how to. I have this code

```
$list = DB::table('transaction_tickets')
   ->leftJoin('airlines','transaction_tickets.airline_id','=','airlines.id')
   ->select('transaction_tickets.*',....)
   ->get();


$inputs = array();
foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    $inputs[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using? 5.2?

Comment: yes I am using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent `get` method returns a collection.

So you can add values to this collection.

Use `$list->put('key', 'value') ;`

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-put)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 has a method to do this for you: [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-pluck)

```
$inputs = $list->pluck($property);
```

For earlier versions of Laravel, you may have to use the `lists()` method instead

```
$inputs = $list->lists($property);
```